# How to SSO to a directory server from a python application

Tags: python-3.x, active-directory, ldap, saml-2.0, apacheds

I am developing a python backend using FastAPI (in docker) and I need to:

- Implement an authentication service that utilizes SSO
- Search the directory for users
- use identity-provider/directory-server in development that is going to be replaced eventually by Microsoft Active Directory (I am developing a mac)

I searched a lot but I am still not sure. What I know now:

- I can use any directory server as long as they support `ldap`
- through `ldap`, I can search the directory
- However, SSO does not seem to be a feature in `ldap`
- SSO can be implemented using `SAML2`

Can you please guide me how to setup this. I am not sure how to integrate `SAML2` and `ldap` to work together in my application.

Comment: why do you need to search for users? Does someone login then use your app to search for users in a directory?

Comment: @codebrane Yes, in a corporate software that's frequently done. One use case, if someone wants to assign a task to a colleague. Another one, selecting the list of reviewers of a certain proposal etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please guide me how to setup this. I am not sure how to integrate SAML2 and ldap to work together in my application.

You will need to set up an identity provider (or find an existing one) that:

1. has support for SAML2 and can act as a SAML2 identity provider.
2. has support for validating user credentials using LDAP and directory servers.

Your application, acting as a SAML2 SP, would send a SAML2 authentication to this IdP. The IdP then asks the user for credentials and validates them against the directory server, and would produce a SAML2 response back to your SP. Your SP would validate and parse the response, and all things permitting, would let the user through.

An example of such an IdP would be: https://github.com/apereo/cas or https://www.shibboleth.net/products/. Both OSS under Apache v2.

Comment: That's great. I will feedback once I implement it. Thank you.